# SDL_Quit() causes SIGBUS error

Tags: c, sdl

The following basic SDL2 code taken from a tutorial website is causing some strange trouble :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define SCREENH 768
#define SCREENW 1366

SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screenSurface = NULL;
SDL_Surface *windowSurface = NULL;

int init_SDL() {
    int success = 0;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
       printf("SDL could not initialize! ");
       printf("SDL_Error: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
       success = -1;
    }
    else {
       window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2_Tutorial02",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SCREENW,SCREENH,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
      if(window == NULL) {
          printf("Window could not be created! ");
          printf("SDL Error: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
      }
      else {
          screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
      }
    }
    return success;
}

int loadMedia() {
    int success = 0;
    windowSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("Images/Hallo.bmp");
    if(windowSurface == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to load image! ");
    printf("SDL Error: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
    success = -1;
    }
    return success;
}

void close() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(windowSurface);
    windowSurface = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    assert(init_SDL() == 0);
    assert(loadMedia() == 0);
    SDL_BlitSurface(windowSurface,NULL,screenSurface,NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Delay(3000);
    close();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

As soon as SDL_Quit(), placed in close(), is invoked I receive a memory access error. Using GDB the following is revealed:

```
49      SDL_Quit();
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x00007ffff68a5895 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
(gdb)
```

The strange about that is when I place SDL_Quit() outside of close() like this:

```
void close() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(windowSurface);
    windowSurface = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    assert(init_SDL() == 0);
    assert(loadMedia() == 0);
    SDL_BlitSurface(windowSurface,NULL,screenSurface,NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Delay(3000);
    close();
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

all things are fine. SDL_Quit() works without error. Why does it cause a SIGBUS Error when I invoke SDL_Quit() in another function ?

EDIT: This code was compiled on ubuntu 14.04 with gcc and the following compile command

```
gcc -g3 -o tutorial tutorial.c `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `close()` is in conflict with an internal SDL function with the same name causing weird behavior (actually, it is the libc standard `close()` syscall called by SDL).

Rename your function and it should be fine.